# How can partial transposition of the Wigner function be achieved in phase space for continuous variables in non-Gaussian states?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, quantum-optics, non-gaussianity

The wigner function in phase space is an equivalent description of the quantum-mechanical density matrix $\rho$. The formula for calculating negativity from the density matrix $\rho$ is $\mathscr{N}(\rho )=\frac{
||\rho^{\rm{T}}_A||_1-1}{2}$.

It is reasonable to believe that some manipulation of the wigner function will also give negativity, the key is how to manipulate the partial transpose in wigner?

I would be grateful if any relevant comments can be given. Or can you help me in recommending articles on this subject. Any relevant answer will be useful for me, thanks!

Comment: @ffz My naive guess would be that the transpose maps $\hat p\to-\hat p$, and thus the partial transpose does so on only one part of the system.

Comment: @Cosmas Zachos Thank you for your reply and browsing through the articles you recommended. Maybe I didn't understand your idea, can you elaborate? My question is how to do partial transpose for Wigner function in phase space?

Comment: @Norbert Schuch Thank you for your answer, in fact your conjecture can be verified from (1-4) of the literature [Inseparability inequalities for higher order
moments for bipartite systems]（https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/7/1/211）. The original idea of the covariance used in the formulae for solving Gaussian states to calculate negativity was to satisfy (4).

Comment: @Norbert Schuch The distressing thing is that although (5) gives a covariance criterion for non-Gaussian states, I still have two questions: 1. I am not sure if (13) in the literature [Dissipation-induced optomechanical entanglement with the assistance of Coulomb interaction]（https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.91.022326） is derived from (4)[Inseparability inequalities for higher order moments for bipartite systems]（iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/7/1/211); 2. Assuming that question 1 is valid, how can I derive the negativity of non-Gaussian states according to (5）

Comment: @ffz Do you mind linking the Arxiv versions?

Comment: @Norbert Schuch  [Inseparability inequalities for higher order moments for bipartite systems](https://doi.org/10.1088/1367-2630/7/1/211) Thanks for pointing that out！